# Error during starting jar file org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm building the jar file, everytime it builds without error, but I have a problems with starting from time to time. If I start it in IDEA it's working everytime.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem, can you tell me which way to look?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'notificationsController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/workspace/CloneMedium/target/ClonMedium-0.1-beta.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ru/javamentor/controll
er/NotificationsController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in
 URL [jar:file:/C:/workspace/CloneMedium/target/ClonMedium-0.1-beta.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/ru/javamentor/service/user/UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3; nested exception is org.springframewo
rk.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationExcep
tion: Error creating bean with name 'getBCryptPasswordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.javamentor")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
/------------------------------------/
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the Java Bean Configuration?

Comment: Please add the configuration as code to your question. Don't let people navigate away to get all the information.

Comment: The error generally indicates you are injecting a bean into the same class it creates. So you probably have both `@Autowired PasswordEncoder` and an `@Bean PasswordEncoder` in your class. Don't do that. Reference the method instead of injecting it. Looking at your code I wonder why you have a login method (as that feels like you are bypassing Spring Security).

Comment: @M.Deinum It's my first time on StackOverflow and I don't know how to mark your answer as correct solution, but it is. Thank you.
"Looking at your code I wonder why you have a login method (as that feels like you are bypassing Spring Security)." I'm new one in this project, just starting go deeper in it. 
Thank you for your answer.